# Using mongodb with java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java, mongo-collection

I'm searching in the database for the URL but with this code I can not. Why? Normally I want to print all the type and the URL where exist in this database. When I have the print only with the type is working but with the print for URL nothing.

```
MongoClient mongoClient;
DB db;

mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
db = mongoClient.getDB("behaviourDB_areas");    


DBCollection cEvent = db.getCollection("event");

    BasicDBObject orderBy = new BasicDBObject();
    orderBy.put("timeStamp",1);


    DBCursor cursorEvents = null;

    BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();
    searchQuery.put("user_id", "55b20db905f333defea9827f");

    cursorEvents = cEvent.find(searchQuery).sort(orderBy);

        int count=0;

        if(cursorEvents.hasNext()){

            while(cursorEvents.hasNext()){

                count++;           

                System.out.println(cursorEvents.next().get("type").toString());
                System.out.println(cursorEvents.next().get("url").toString());
                System.out.println(count);
            }   
        }

        mongoClient.close();
    }   
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Are there any error messages? What are you expecting to happen? What type of collection you use? How does the data looks like exactly?

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.....I am new with all this ...with mongodb...with java....am trying!!

Comment: Just basic stackoverflow guidelines ;)

Comment: When i try to run it ..i take this(in the first picture)...and the data it must be like (in the second picture).But my i want to take only the type and when appears url i want it too. The type of collections is what happen when someone navigate on internet....and have to find every type of actions in every page.                                                                       (picture_1)   http://i.stack.imgur.com/KvNjr.jpg                                                                                           (picture_2)    http://i.stack.imgur.com/eKybw.jpg

Comment: which version of mongo-driver are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cursor.next()` should be called only once, calling it second time will return next document. [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next())

`NullPointerException` could be thrown because next document does not exist or `get("url")` returns `null`.

Following snippet should solve both issues.

```
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
    MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("behaviourDB_areas");
    MongoCollection cEvent = db.getCollection("event", Document.class);

    MongoCursor<Document> cursorEvents = cEvent
            .find(new BasicDBObject("user_id", "55b20db905f333defea9827f"))
            .sort(new BasicDBObject("timeStamp",1))
            .iterator();

    int count = 0;

    if(cursorEvents.hasNext()) {
        Document doc = cursorEvents.next();
        System.out.println(doc.getString("type"));
        if (doc.containsKey("url")) {
            System.out.println(doc.getString("url"));
        }
        System.out.println(++count);
    }

    cursorEvents.close();
    mongoClient.close();
```